# How can a CCMenu have a SIGSEV crash error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

`cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1`. I am receiving several `SIGSEV` crash reports on two parts:

**CCMenu.m**:

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSAssert(state_ == kCCMenuStateTrackingTouch, @"[Menu ccTouchEnded] -- invalid state");

    [selectedItem_ unselected];
    [selectedItem_ activate];   // <--- Here

    state_ = kCCMenuStateWaiting;
}
```

**CCMenuItem.m**:

```
-(void) activate {
    if(isEnabled_)
        [invocation_ invoke];   // <--- Here
}
```

I have several backtraces, but they don't provide useful insight on my code - they all refer to cocos2d, CoreFoundation or UIKit libraries. A sample one:

```
0   MyGame  0x002609f0      testflight_backtrace
1   MyGame  0x002602d8      TFSignalHandler
2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x3bdfa062  _sigtramp
3   CoreFoundation  0x312e4da2  -[NSInvocation invoke]
4   MyGame  0x000ee9f2  -[CCMenuItem activate] in CCMenuItem.m on Line 128
5   MyGame  0x000ed9be  -[CCMenu ccTouchEnded:withEvent:] in CCMenu.m on Line 201
6   MyGame  0x0010e26a  -[CCTouchDispatcher touches:withEvent:withTouchType:] in CCTouchDispatcher.m on Line 268
7   MyGame  0x0010e67e  -[CCTouchDispatcher touchesEnded:withEvent:] in CCTouchDispatcher.m on Line 337
8   MyGame  0x0010f5d8  -[EAGLView touchesEnded:withEvent:] in EAGLView.m on Line 330
9   UIKit   0x33b3ddd8  -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
10  UIKit   0x33b38e64  -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
...
```

I'm still trying to replicate this myself. What I DO know is that `selectedItem_` is probably a zombie object because I did manage to replicate it very long ago. This didn't help me much though.

My game has several `CCMenu` instances everywhere, and I'm under the impression that many of those menus are culprits, not just one. I must be doing something funny with them, but I can't figure out what.

Instead, I would like to know, **what kind of code could possibly cause a SIGSEV error on a `CCMenu`**?

Comment: Please show frames 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Ok. These are TestFlight calls.

Comment: I think you will need to run the code in a debugger and trap when it crashes.  It could be anything causing this.

Comment: more info needed: did you modify any of CCMenu or CCMenuItem (and subclasses) code? Are you using ARC or MRC? Do you, at any time, remove children of a CCMenu to remove specific menu items? Do you use any threading code in your app (GCD dispatch async, NSThread, performSelectorInBackground, etc)? Also: run the app with zombie objects enabled until you found this bug.